# Can we use Log in Android to know the sequential flow of thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-fragments, android-asynctask

How can I know the flow if more than two threads are in use , as in case of any networking library like VOLLEY , ASYSNCTASK etc .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the sequence of threads by logging, but by definition you can't possibly know when exactly threads will execute since it's not deterministic. Who decides this is the kernel based on some internal rules and Android has some "layers" built on top of the Linux Kernel that allow you to somehow control the priority of your threads. What this means is: everytime you run your application the order of the methods inside threads will change.

I recommend you to watch this presentation where this is explained in detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQoc1nSvvMw

There is one tool that can help you to debug threads: Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS) https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html

Here is a post explaining how to use it https://www.toptal.com/android/android-ddms-ultimate-power-console